# Page refreshes after redirect because of image upload

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

When I submit the form, some data is inserted into the db and an image is uploaded.

The whole thing works, however if an image is uploaded, then the page refreshes **on its own** after form submission. It returns with a redirect and then **refreshes again**. It is really weird.

Here is relevant code from the `post` method:

```
...

productRepo.save(product);
Files.write(path, bytes); // because of this line the page refreshes after redirect

return "redirect:/admin/products/add";
```

So as it says in the comment above, when using `Files.write` the page refreshes twice, it returns and then refreshes again. If I comment out that line everything works as expected (just one return, and no page refresh after that).

Why is file uploading causing the page to refresh after redirect?

Comment: Your browser's devtool is your friend. Look at the requests / responses in network tab.

Comment: Turned out to be the live server which restarted when it detected a new image was uploaded for some reason